# How can I store .RData file in MongoDB

Tags: r, mongodb

I built Logistic regression model using RStudio, the result is store as log_lr.RData, so i want to store this result (object) in MongoDB.

Have you one idea to help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Please add more details (e.g. minimal non-working example) so that others can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You can `save` or `saveRDS` to a `rawConnection` to put your data to a raw variable in R, then use the `mongolite` package to get it into MongoDB as binary data.

```
x <- 1:10
con <- rawConnection(raw(0), open = "r+")
save(x, file=con)
mydata <- rawConnectionValue(con)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks you for your answer, but i trie this and i get this error :                  > Error in toJSON(mydata) : unable to convert R type 24 to JSON                    Can you give more example about how can i insert mydata in mongoDB ?